# Как взять высоту одного блока и присвоить её другому? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно нужно брать высоту одного блока и при загрузке документа присваивать его другому. Как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать JQuery, то довольно доходчиво это описано на [сайте самого jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/height/), суть всех действий примерно такая:

```
$(function() {
    var height = $( '#elementId1' ).height(); //получаем высоту одного элемента
    $( '#elementId2' ).height(height); //записываем высоту другому элементу
});
```

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить `$(function(){ ... })` т.к. необходимо это сделать после загрузки документа

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, но мне кажется, что оборачивать в функцию должен уже тот, кто будет использовать код, никто не знает, как там устроена обработка данного события, может там уже есть такая функция

Comment: тс написал же `при загрузке документа`, я так полагаю это значит ровно то, что значит =)

Comment: Почему-то любой элемент определяется с высотой только 30 px. То есть любой элемент в переменной... хотя изначально там высота другая... Как-то не понятно считает

Comment: Думаю стоит повесить еще и [триггер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute)

Comment: А можете пример кода здесь описать, пожалуйста ?

Answer (score 0):

Действительно проблема, только постоянный контроль =((
https://jsfiddle.net/q2h1p87b/

```
function checkForChanges()
{
  $("#block2").height($("#block1").height()); 
  setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}
checkForChanges();
```

по этой же проблеме [jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628450/jquery-how-to-determine-if-a-div-changes-its-height-or-any-css-attribute)